# Unable to hide login button after logged in using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to hide the login and register button once the user is registered. It doesn't work as expected as it hides the login and SIGN UP butoon, but it doesn't bring them back once logged out. Below is the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code.

```
   <div class="login"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">LOG IN</a></div>

   <div class="login"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SIGN UP</a></div>

   $message = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
   <div class="message">
        <?php
        echo "$message";
        ?>
    </div>
```

Below is the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    x = $(".message").text().length;
    if ( x >=1) {
        $(".login").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#logout").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: show us the contents of `.message` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show the buttons as you have hidden them while login. You need to change the code like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    x = $(".message").text().trim(); 
    if ( !!x) { 
        $(".login").hide(); 
        $("#logout").show(); 
    } 
    else { 
        $("#logout").hide(); 
        $(".login").show(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: dint work, is seems some problem with ".message" as .message takes session variables once logged in

Comment: So you need to clear the session variable if your login fails or logout triggers so the message div would be empty and can enter the else condition.

Comment: I am doing same only still not working. Well Ashis can you pls help me with your version of code maybe new one

Comment: I think you might have some issue with the enter and spaces, as i can see much space and gap within the div tag. So i have used the trim operator. Please now try updated code and let me know.

Comment: You are overusing jQuery a bit here. [AFAIK](http://www.internetslang.com/AFAIK-meaning-definition.asp) `$(".message").text().trim().length` does the same thing.

Comment: Even better: `!!$(".message").text().trim()`. This will return `false` if the string only contains white space and no text, and in the if statement, just use `x` instead of `x >= 1`.

Comment: guys pls help me in this post as well

Comment: unable to close modal window once form submitted    need help in this post as well, put as a seperate question